# MYSQL Error 1064: Create Event

Tags: mysql

Still new to MySQL. Where did I go wrong in my syntax?

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_1 (column_name) SELECT column FROM table_1 WHERE column REGEXP 'regex_string'
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that `BEGIN` and `END` since it's not a compound statement and also if your column name is `column` then escape it like

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
INSERT INTO table_1 (column_name) 
   SELECT `column` FROM table_1 
   WHERE `column` REGEXP 'regex_string';
```

Refer [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help.